# Is there any data structure or library in C++ can work like Python List and Dictionary

Tags: c++, python, list, dictionary

Is there any data  structure or library in C++ can work like Python List and Dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I wouldn't say that a list -> linked-list.  list objects are indexible for example.  They're more like dynamic arrays (but I don't know what C++ has as far as those are concerned).

Comment: @JoranBeasley Python's `list` **is** a dynamic array. It's (basically) the same data structure as `std::vector`, and nothing like `std::list`.

Comment: @delnan -- Yes...with some operations to make using them a little nicer (e.g. `remove`, `insert` ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Python's `list`**

  Standard `std::vector<>` is probably what you need. However, unlike Python's `list`, standard C++ containers are **not heterogeneous**: a `std::vector<T>` will exclusively store `T` instances. You could achieve similar behavior through the use of [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/), [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/), or polymorphism depending on the use case.
- **Python's `dict`**

  For a dictionary, you can look into `std::map<>`, or perhaps more exactly for [`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/unordered.html), as `map` is in fact a red-black tree.